# Powershell Revoke Certificate

Tags: powershell, pki, certificate-authority

I want to remove the Certificate for a user and his computer.
I have tried:

```
Import-Module PSPKI
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$RequesterNameComputer = "A\B$";
$RequesterNameUser = "A\C"; 

certutil -view -out "RequestID,SerialNumber,RequesterName,RequestType,NotAfter,CommonName" csv > "$env:TEMP\tempcerts.csv";

$Csv = Import-Csv -Path "$env:TEMP\tempcerts.csv";
$csv | Select-Object "requester name" | Group-Object -Property "requester name" | Sort-Object -Property count;

$computer = $csv | Where-Object {$_."requester name" -eq $RequesterNameComputer} | ?{$_."Certificate Template" -like "*PlaygroundComputer"}; 
$computer

$User = $csv | Where-Object {$_."requester name" -eq $RequesterNameUser} | ?{$_."Certificate Template" -like "*User"};
$User
```

I know I have to use `certutil -revoke` but do not know how to adjust it to my script so that it deletes all certificate which shows $Computer and $User.

Comment: You most certainly don't want to revoke a CA for a particular user/computer. That wouldn't make any sense. Do you mean you want to delete the CA certificate from the user's computer? Or do you want to revoke the user's (computer's?) certificate?

Comment: why removing the particular User/Computer doesnt make any sense? I want to revoke the User's and Computer's Certificate when he leaves the company forexample.

Comment: Revoking the CA doesn't make sense. Revoking the user and/or computer certificate is not the same.

Comment: You are right. I meant revoking the User and Computer's CA. by $Computer I get the Computer CA and bei $User I get User CA and I want to revoke the results.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion of ideas here. CA does not mean "certificate". It's an acronym for "Certification Authority", i.e. an instance that issues and revokes certificates. Please clarify what exactly it is you're trying to do, where exactly you're doing it, and what the related infrastructure looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Import-Module PSPKI
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$RequesterNameComputer = "A\B";
$RequesterNameUser = "A\C"; 

#certutil: display information about the digital certificates that are installed on a DirectAccess client, DirectAccess server, or intranet resource.
certutil -view -out "RequestID,SerialNumber,RequesterName,RequestType,NotAfter,CommonName,Certificate Template" csv > "$env:TEMP\tempcerts.csv";

$Csv = Import-Csv -Path "$env:TEMP\tempcerts.csv";
$csv | Select-Object "requester name" | Group-Object -Property "requester name" | Sort-Object -Property count;

$computer = $csv | Where-Object {$_."requester name" -eq $RequesterNameComputer} | ?{$_."Certificate Template" -like "*PlaygroundComputer"}; 
$computer

ForEach ($com in $computer){
certutil -revoke $com.'Serial Number' 5;
}

# certutil -installdefaulttemplates  
$User = $csv | Where-Object {$_."requester name" -eq $RequesterNameUser} | ?{$_."Certificate Template" -like "*User"};
$User

foreach ($usr in $User){
certutil -revoke $usr.'Serial Number' 5;
}

Remove-Item -Path "$env:TEMP\tempcerts.csv" -Force;
```